# How do you change bullet/numbered list format of only certain parts?

Tags: microsoft-word, bullets

```
1.
  1.1.
    1.1.1.
    1.1.2.
2.
  2.1.
  2.2.
3.
  3.1.
4.
  4.1.
    4.1.1
...
```

Let's say a bulleted list goes like this. I want to change the bullet format for specific parts, without changing the rest, like this:

```
1.
  1.1.
    1.1.1.
    1.1.2.
2.
  (1)
  (2)
3.
  (1)
4.
  4.1
    4.1.1
...
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your list following the directions found at How to [Create Numbered Lists by Shauna Kelly](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) [Windows] or [Outline Numbering for OSX by John Korchok](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/) [Mac].

These give the same method but the controls are in different places. The basic idea is to attach each level of a list to an existing paragraph style.

If your are only using three or four levels for your main numbering, use a level 8 or 9 numbering for your different numbering. You can control the indents and other settings in the Define New Multilevel List dialog. You apply the numbering by applying the styles, not by using the numbering controls in the ribbon.

[image: Define New MultiLevel List Dialog]

*Note that this dialog shows numbering starting at 2. That is because took this when I was in a part of the document where it was 2. The numbering actually starts at 1.* **Here is a screenshot from the sample document.**

[image: Sample prepared using techniques - screenshot]

**Here is a [temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83tzex5n71p7rq0/deleteme%20headings.docx?dl=0) to a sample document set up this way.**

Answer (score 0):

One simple-minded and low tech way is to put a plain enter or two between sections.

Then format each section.

You can delete (not backspace) the extra enters when done.

I do this frequently because it is easy and works.

Here is a sample Word Document that took a couple of minutes or less to create. I left the spaces in so you can see that. I would delete spaces I do not need to polish.

Again, I like things simple and this accomplishes this for me.

[image]

Comment: The method is not automatic, but it is straightforward as I posted to allow different formatting of different parts. It is easy (for me) to do on the fly.  So  Bullet 1 , repeat, enter, enter, Bullet 2, repeat and so on. Go back and delete spaces (without undoing format).

Comment: Yes. Typing numbers is simpler, until you start editing.

Comment: So, you are recommending not using automatic numbering for the second set of numbers but simply typing them. Yes, that will work. Sorry for being so obtuse.

Comment: I use automatic numbering / bullets as needed, space, space, new automatic numbering / bullets as needed, repeat as needed, Go back and edit and within the group automatic numbering works. At the end, delete excess spaces.  It is just so simple and so easy that I use it. I like simplicity in operation

Comment: I have some difficulty following your process. That may be true of others as well. It would be helpful if you could save a document that uses this method on DropBox or OneDrive and edit your answer with a link to that. ----- If you are interspersing automatic lists it could be problematic. Search Google for "Word spaghetti numbering."  Search the first article listed for "spaghetti."

Comment: I edited my post and I think it is clear to follow. You can see the variety of bullets and I can, in fact, go back and edit and add with the style formatting where I am editing.